# What's the best way to close the Spring Applicationcontext?

Tags: spring

There  is two  way  to  close the Spring ApplicationContext:

**Solution 1:**

```
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring/application-context.xml");
         // Application core ...
         ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "spring/application-context.xml");
        ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).registerShutdownHook();
        // Application core ...
```

What's the difference between this 2 solutions and what's the best in terms of performance ?

Comment: Why are you even loading your own context if you are using Spring Boot? The latter doesn't close anything it tries to cleanup stuff when the JVM is exiting.

Comment: Sorry @M.Deinum, i'm not using Spring Boot.

Comment: According to your tags you where. If you are in a web application you shouldn't create a context, also a context should be created once and not everytime you need a bean or something else the context provides. So the question is do you really need this because you are building a standalone application or ....

Comment: @M.Deinum  I'm using Spring to build a standalone application, i'm not in case of a web application, so i need to create  the context and destroying it in the end of the application as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 shuts down the application context

Solution 2 registers a callback, so spring will shut down, if the JVM is shut down, from javadoc :

> Register a shutdown hook with the JVM runtime, closing this context on JVM shutdown unless it has already been closed at that time.

So both are two diffrent things, normally you will call registerShutdownHook() directly after you created the appication context. So when your user terminates the JVM, spring will be called and shuts itself down.

You should call close() when your application ends, to allow spring to destroy its beans.